# Multiple Forms C++

Tags: c++, winforms

I want to know if there is a way of manipulating controls in a form that is not open yet. For example, say I enter text in a textbox on Form1. Is it possible to make that text appear on a textbox in Form2 *before* Form2 is opened?

Comment: I want to have two forms, The second form opens when a password is entered in the first form. I want the second form to show what has been entered in the first from (let's call the second form an 'admin' kind of). Can you help?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Google for one of the *million* posts here that pass variables from one form to another.

Comment: Showing the form and creating the form are two different steps. First you need to create the form. At this point you can manipulate any property and component inside the form, so you can change the text in your textbox on Form2. Then you can call the show method to display it.

Comment: And if you want to make your life easier, do not mix C++ and .NET. Both are *great*, but C++/CLI is the mixture of the cryptic syntax of C++ with the runtime disadvantages of .NET. Don't pick the worst of both worlds by forcing them together. Pick one and stay with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the text by passing it using the second form's constructor. I'll be using pseudocode here

in form1:

```
form2 f2(string text); // create an instance of the second form
// display the form
```

in form2:

```
public: // constructor
     form2(string text_pwd){
         pwd = text_pwd;
     }
private:
    string pwd;
```